# Dividing an image into two non-rectangular non-square sub-image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, binary, divide

Assume that I have an image like this:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015a/examples/images/BasicImageImportProcessingAndExportExample_03.png

(It is original image in matlab  **pout.tif**)

And help image (binary mask) like this:
http://upload7.ir/uploads//df17be22203e3099ba0d86e7cb203477bc909244.jpg

(With the same size of the original image)

I wrote this simple code for dividing the original image into two images:

```
I=imread('pout.tif');
figure,imshow(I),title('original image')

Ih=imread('helpPic.jpg');
Ih=rgb2gray(Ih);
Ih=im2bw(Ih);
figure,
imshow(Ih),title('help image')

im1=I.*uint8(Ih);
figure,
imshow(im1),title('im1')

im2=I.*uint8(1-Ih);
figure,
imshow(im2),title('im2')
```

And results:

http://upload7.ir/uploads//12f09dde101cd4c98b53fcc0d400be87029ee07a.png

And know I want to implement Otsu's method to binarize this sub images(im1 and im2), How can I implement otsu's method **only** on part with information (non zero part of sub images) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`graythresh`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html) function in the Image Processing Toolbox implements Otsu's method. Furthermore, as Otsu's method only cares about the *values* of the pixels and not their position, you can rearrange the pixels of interest in a one-dimentional array before applying `graythresh`.

In pratice, this gives the -compact- following code :

```
level1 = graythresh(I(Ih(:)));
level2 = graythresh(I(~Ih(:)));
```

Best,

Comment: thanks for your answer dear @Crazy Rat , I do that but I got error (**Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals**), How can I remove this error?

Comment: @Karo AMini: You are right, I've checked this and edited my answer.

Comment: dear @Crazy Rat we should use   `~Ih` instead of  `1-Ih` to remove the error. thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark the question as answered if this is the case, such that the community knows you no longer need help on this.

Comment: Dear @Crazy RaT ,I should do some operation on my image, may I ask for your help about this question here ?

Comment: @Karo Amini: You'd better open a new question. As I may not be able to answer (I'm not perfect), you will increase your chances to get a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since Matlab's `graythresh`(which implements Otsu's method to compute the threshold) uses I(:) and ignores the dimensions of I (you can see that if you `edit gryythresh`), you can just use

```
t = graythresh(im(im_mask))
```

To compute the threshold over the region where the mask is 1.

Comment: thanks for your advise. support and love Israel from Kurdistan.